# Determine if wallpaper is set on x11

Tags: c++, x11

I am trying to determine if wallpaper is set on my x11 desktop. For that I am getting color of pixel using below code. The problem is that even when no wallpaper is set, It returns some random rgb values as 18 23 50, whereas I expected it to be 00 00 00 (black). Am I missing something?

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    XColor c;
    // Open a display.
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    // Get the root of the display
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(d);

    printf("Deafult root window %x\n", root);
    // Map the root window
    XMapWindow(d, root);

    // Get width and height of the display
    int windowHeight = XDisplayHeight (d, 0);
    int windowWidth = XDisplayWidth(d, 0);

    
    // Get dump of screen
    XImage *image = XGetImage(d, root, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);

    c.pixel = XGetPixel(image,100,100);
    printf("%d %d %lu\n", windowHeight, windowWidth, c.pixel);

    XQueryColor (d, XDefaultColormap(d, XDefaultScreen (d)), &c);
    cout << c.red/256 << " " << c.green/256 << " " << c.blue/256 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the X11 API, but 18 23 50 is pretty close to black to the naked eye.  How confident are you that it's not the actual value?

Comment: Since there is no wallpaper set, I expect it to be exactly black. I confirmed it with color picker as well. Since the task is to determine if wallpaper is set or not, the close to black information will not suffice if wallpaper will have close to black colors.